# Can I specify files from other directories to be added in a git repository?

Tags: linux, git

I have a git repository called "workspace" which I add my code so I can access it from different machines. I wanted to add my code editor config files without copy pasting them every time or without using a hard link because there are also directories. I learned that I can mount the config directory to my git repository and solved the issue. But is there a way to do this without mounting? Can I configure my .git file to include another repository?

Comment: A git repository can only contain files that are contained in the same directory the contains the `.git` directory or one of its children. It cannot include files from "outside" of the top-level directory.

Comment: You can use git submodules, but they can be painful to use.